# When I include a script for sliding in vue js.. the sliding didnot happen and alignment changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

This is the script for sliding

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {

          $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel({
                visibleItems: 5,
                animationSpeed: 1000,
                autoPlay: true,
                autoPlaySpeed: 3000,            
                pauseOnHover: false,
                enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                responsiveBreakpoints: { 
                    portrait: { 
                        changePoint:480,
                        visibleItems: 2
                    }, 
                    landscape: { 
                        changePoint:640,
                        visibleItems: 3
                    },
                    tablet: { 
                        changePoint:800,
                        visibleItems: 4
                    }
                }
            });
            });
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
</script>
```

When I include in the vue js file.. it looks as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Vue({ 
    el: '#featured' , 
    data: { 
      data: {}, 
    }, 
    mounted() { 

        $(window).load(function() {

          $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel({
                visibleItems: 5,
                animationSpeed: 1000,
                autoPlay: true,
                autoPlaySpeed: 3000,            
                pauseOnHover: false,
                enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                responsiveBreakpoints: { 
                    portrait: { 
                        changePoint:480,
                        visibleItems: 2
                    }, 
                    landscape: { 
                        changePoint:640,
                        visibleItems: 3
                    },
                    tablet: { 
                        changePoint:800,
                        visibleItems: 4
                    }
                }
            });
            });

       var self = this;

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
      function success(position) {
        var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';
        $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
            $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
          $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
        })

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        $.ajax({
          url: post/filter/',
          data: {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lon: position.coords.longitude,
          },
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (e) { 
            if (e.status == 1) { 
              self.data = e.data; 
              console.log(e.data) 
            }
          }
        });
        console.log(lat);
      }

      function error(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

But when I use this vue js.. the alignment completely changes and I sliding also does not happen.. What is my mistake? Is there any problem by using in this way

My html file NOW after using vue js is as

```
<div class="featured">
<div v-for="row in data">
{{row.id}}</div></div>
```

Without using vue js.. it was as

```
 <ul id="flexiselDemo1">
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Can antbody please help me to sort what the problem is.. I am really stuck and have no idea how to move forward.. Is there any any error in the way I used the sliding script inside vue js script tag. Please help me to obtain a solution?

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to mix jQuery with Vue, especially here since it doesn't look like you're really using Vue at all, you're just running everything inside mounted() -- why not just code this with jQuery? Are you actually loading jQuery on the site? Or just Vue?

Comment: I need to load both jquery and vue

Comment: both jquery and vue have id.. how can I able to manage that

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: sir my problem arises since there are two id 's . One id for flexiselDemo1 to manage sliding and other comes for vue js. So, how can I able to manage these two id's without a conflict

Comment: how can I manage two id's ??

Comment: Just use different ids? #featured for the Vue el and #flexiselDemo1 for the slider

Comment: how to use that two id's ? when I use that two id's as above.. conflict arises for me

Comment: is the above code is correct?